# i am having this error(at onBackpressed block) after exiting app should i go with this error or if not please tell me how to fix it

Tags: java, android, exception

i am having this error(at onBackpressed block) after exiting app should i go with this error or if not please tell me how to fix it

Thanks all my question was fix by you guys

Comment: please add some bunch of code of ```MainActivity.java``` related with this error.

Comment: i add .java photo please check it

Comment: if I am not wrong, You want to exit your app on double back pressed on back button. RIGHT?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when the element that is being requested doesn't exist.
your photo is not so clear, please send Line 181 of Main Activity to check.

Comment: i upload it please check it

Comment: why you are poping the item that is presented at the top stack, line 181? as you know, this method returns the element that is presented at the top of the stack and after that, this method removes that item, I think your problem is in line 183 because maybe you have just one fragment in your stack and so the size of your stack is 1, after pop method in line 181 your stack is empty, so you can not access the item that does not exist in stack.

Answer (score 1):

This is Working Code of this Functionality.

---

**YourMAinActivity.java**

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (fragment instanceof YourFragmentName) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
        } else if (fragment instanceof YourFragmentName) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false, 2000);

        }
```

---

TRY this code. This is worked for me. THANKS. ;)